# Distance of footnote number from theorem title

Tags: formatting, footnotes, theorems

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}
\begin{theorem}[Something]\footnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image]

> I feel that the footnote number should be nearer to the theorem title. In my document the situation is even worse, because I have normal text instead of italic. Is is possible to change the theorem style in such a way that if the following command is a `\footnote`, the distance is reduced. Or some other trick, because the problem is a real blot on the landscape.

Comment: For me may be you should put the `\footnote` inside the brackets `\begin{theorem}[Something\footnote{Something}]`

Comment: Not ideal, but `amsthm` has `\nopunct` which can be used to suppress the period. Then, `\begin{theorem}[Something\footnote{Something}.\nopunct]` with an explicit period.  (It won't be bold, but that's the tradeoff.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The main problem with the `\nopunct` approach is that it is not possible then to add a footnote if there is no title.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda The problem is in case that there is no title (50% / 50% in my case)

Comment: You are right in case that there is no title there is a problem

Comment: @PeptideChain -- Unfortunately, I'm unable to test (no available tex system at the moment).  If no title, I'd look at defining a `\newtheoremstyle` and including the facility for a footnote directly into the heading text.  But what is the nature of the footnote content?  An actual example would be very instructive here.  (Substitute plausible data if you don't want to divulge anything confidential, but make it exactly parallel to your actual case.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton most of the time is the source. In general is some information that is needed, but is of no help to read the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple, but effective, solution is to use a negative horizontal space to move back the footnote. Unless you have thousands of theorems and footnotes, it is maybe also the *most* effective solution (but I agree it is not a very sophisticated solution):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Something}

\begin{theorem}[Something]\hspace{-0.5em}\footnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: smart idea! thank you.