# Definition of an alternative to \footnote to adjust the layout

Tags: macros

This is a follow up question of [Distance of footnote number from theorem title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502302/)

I've problems defining my `\thfootnote`. The problem concern the optional argument of the `\footnote` command as you see in the MEW

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\thfootnote}[2][]{\hspace{-0.4em}\footnote[#1]{#2}\hspace{0.3em}}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}
\begin{theorem}[Something]\footnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Something]\thfootnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example prints `Missing number, treated as zero`. TeX wants a number for the `#1` and, in the absence of a number, inserts `0`. That's why you see 0. It's easy to do something special if `#1` is blank or empty, but which number do you want to see in the footnote text in this case, since there would presumably be no mark? Isn't it going to be confusing to have a footnote without any number or symbol at the point where it is “called”?

Comment: @frougon The idea is to preserve the behaviour of \footnote, thus inclusive the optional parameter. That is: \foonote{Something} assign the next footnote number according to latex logic;  \foonote[113]{Something} assign the  footnote number 113. Theoretically (how?) in the macro one should chek if the optional parameter is empty do \footnote{#2} otherwise \footnote[#1]{#2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504407/definition-of-an-alternative-to-footnote-to-adjust-the-layout/504418#comment1274220_504407), I believe this is what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\thfootnote}[2][]{%
  \hspace{-0.4em}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{\footnote}{\footnote[#1]}%
  {#2}\hspace{0.3em}}

\begin{document}

\section{Something}

\begin{theorem}[Something]\footnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Something]\thfootnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

(There is no need to include the `{#2}` in both alternatives, because TeX is a macro language—it *could* be included without harm, though.)

In case you want to tolerate spaces inside the optional argument of `\thfootnote` (treating a blank optional argument as an empty one), just replace `\ifstrempty` with `\ifblank`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the purpose of `\thfootnote` is, but if you want to get rid of the space without writing `\hspace{-0.4em}` before every footnote in a theorem, you may define your new footnote with only one argument. You then hook it to the numbering of the other footnotes. See the MWE. If the purpose is something different, please elaborate your question.

If you need more that one footnote series, you should have a look at [bigfoot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) or [manyfoot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot). Also, be aware that the standard article class does not place the footnotes at the bottom of the page, but in a fixed distance from the text. You should therefor consider loading footmisc with the option `bottom`, or using one of the [KOMA-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\thfootnote}[1]{\hspace{-0.4em}\footnote{#1}\hspace{0.3em}}
\begin{document}
\section{Something}
\begin{theorem}[Something]\footnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Something]\thfootnote{Something}
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[\footnote{Something}]
Blah blah.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see my comment to @frougon. But at the end, after reflecting on it, I will never need the optional parameter of \footnote